# Select one of 4 random directions with rand()?

Tags: c++, c, random

I want to choose randomly from among 4 directions:

```
movePlayer(map, &positionPlayer, direction);
```

where direction is one of `UP`, `DOWN`, `LEFT`, and `RIGHT`.

I haven't yet found out how to do this with the `rand()` function.

How can I do this? Do I need to assign a number to each direction and then choose a random number within those bounds?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using an enum for the direction helps a lot.

Comment: These directions are already in an enum, what is the next step ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to simply do a modulos of the rand function to get a numbers between 0 and 3(inclusive).

```
int x = rand() % 4;
```

Then you can simply perform a switch statement to choose the direction

```
switch(x)
{
   case 0:
      movePlayer(map, &positionPlayer, UP);
      break;

   case 1:
      movePlayer(map, &positionPlayer, DOWN);
      break;

   case 2:
      movePlayer(map, &positionPlayer, LEFT);
      break;

   case 3:
      movePlayer(map, &positionPlayer, RIGHT);
      break;
}
```

Of course, this will not be exactly random with a perfect distrubition( the modulus is somewhat of a hack).

If you want real randomness with actual distributions then you might want to look into Boost.Random.

Comment: How is this the easiest? It would be one line with an enum and a cast.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need assign a number to each direction.
ie. 0=UP 1=DOWN 2=LEFT 3=RIGHT
You need code like this:

```
int direction = rand()%4;
```

Comment: That's where the enum comes in handy.

Answer (score 2):

If `direction` is an enum:

```
enum Direction {
    UP,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
} direction;
```

In C/C++, enumeration constants are represented as integers. The first value, `UP`, corresponds to 0, `DOWN` is 1, and so forth.

So you can just call:

```
movePlayer(map, &positionPlayer, static_cast<Direction>(rand() % 4));
```

which will call `movePlayer` with a randomly chosen direction value.

It is not always advisable to just use the modulus operator to narrow down the range of `rand()`. If you need something with a more uniform distribution, you should look into [other methods](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx) of doing so.

Comment: I'm using codeblocks and C:    error: 'static_cast' undeclared (first use in this function)|

Comment: Why is the question tagged with C++ if you are not using C++?

Comment: @capslock, if you're using C, `(Diection)(rand() % 4)` will have to suffice.

Comment: @chris: If you're using C, then `rand() % 4` will suffice, since integers can be implicitly converted to enumerations.

Answer (score 2):

rand() isn't necessarily very good. `<random>` is probably a better option.

C++11:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

enum Direction : char {
  north, east, south, west
};

std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &os, Direction d) {
  switch (d) {
    case Direction::north : return os << "North";
    case Direction::east  : return os << "East";
    case Direction::south : return os << "South";
    case Direction::west  : return os << "West";
  }
}

std::uniform_int_distribution<Direction> random_direction
  {Direction::north, Direction::west};

int main() {
  // you can use any of several different sources of random values depending on your needs
  std::mt19937 eng;
  for (int i=0;i<10;++i)
    std::cout << random_direction(eng) << '\n';
}
```

If you don't want the directions to be implicitly convertible to int you can use an `enum class` and a different definition for `random_direction`:

```
template<typename Engine>
Direction random_direction(Engine &&eng) {
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist
    {int(Direction::north),int(Direction::west)};
  return Direction(dist(std::forward<Engine>(eng)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to call srand(time(0)) before rand()%4.
This would ensure that each time you execute your program, different set of random numbers would be generated.
Calling rand() without srand() would generate the same set of random numbers each time the program is executed.